# What are the advantages of the 2nd _.once implementation?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to understand how the _.once function works in underscore

```
_.once = function(func) {
  var alreadyCalled = false;
  return function() {
    if (!alreadyCalled) {
      alreadyCalled = true;
      return func();
    }
  };
};


_.once = function(func) {
   var alreadyCalled = false;
   var result;
   return function() {
     if (!alreadyCalled) {
       result = func.apply(this, arguments);
       alreadyCalled = true;
     }
     return result;
  };
};
```

Is the 2nd one more flexible in that it can use arguments if they are passed to func?

Comment: That, and the fact that calling the second function more than once will actually return the first result, whereas calling the first one will return `undefined` after the first call, which could be an undesirable behavior.